# C4.5 Decision tree making algorithm

Tags: algorithm, decision-tree

I need to implement C4.5 decision tree creating algorithm and be able to make some changes in it. That's why i cannot use some third-party calculation library.

Using uncle Google I was only able to find information about ID3 algorithm.

Could you provide the c# (the better option) or pseudo-code of this algorithm?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm

Comment: You ask about description of the algorithm itself, or guidance in the implementation in the specific language?

Comment: Googling for `id3 c4.5 quinlan` does the trick. BTW: c# will pull in a 3rd party library.

Comment: I did try to find answer in google. The pseudocode in Wiki is for generic decision tree algorithm, not C4.5-specific. I'm looking for source code of implementation of this algorithm.